# React: Store <Form> data from to MySQL

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot

I have created a register page in `reactjs`, where I am taking `firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, `email` from a user.

In the backend, I have created the application using `SpringBoot` to handle the request from frontend.

- Now, I am able to store (temporarily) the register form data in `http://localhost:8080/forms` .
- When the user enters the data in register `form` at the front end, the data is stored temporarily in the spring boot application in the url mentioned in the axios.
- So, when I enter this url (in the browser), am able to see the list of registered users with their credentials in JSON format like this :

```
[{"firstName":"Bhavya", "lastName":"Gupta", "email":"abcd@a", "password":"zaqxsw","id":100}]
```

- But this data is temporarily stored, so when I restart the server the data is no longer there.

```js
submitBook= event =>{
  event.preventDefault();
  const book = {
    firstName:  this.state.firstName,
    lastName: this.state.lastName,
    password: this.state.password,
    email: this.state.email
  };

  axios.post("http://localhost:8080/forms",book).then(response => {
    if(response.data!=null){
      this.setState({"show":true});
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({"show":false}),3000);
    } else {
      this.setState({"show":false});
    }
  });
  this.setState(this.initialState);
}
```

The complete code is available [here](https://github.com/bhavya121999/forms)

**I want to store the register `form` data from front-end (client-side) into a `MySQL` database, so that I can perform login authentication on the data stored.**

I have created MySQL database with 4 columns - firstName, lastName, email, password.
 I searched on the internet and read several answers in SO [Sending data to database in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332643/sending-data-to-database-in-react-js-web-application), referred several blogs and articles, but I am not able to understand how to achieve this.

Can anyone please help me out in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Posting Form data from ReactJS to MySQL database via Spring Boot Application, I have written blogs, that gives a detailed explanation and a step by step method to connect front end part with backend .**

Refer to these blogs :

[Prerequisites to POST form data from ReactJS to an API endpoint : Part 1](https://medium.com/@bhavyagupta1203/prerequisites-to-post-form-data-from-reactjs-to-an-api-endpoint-aef1f6b193aa)

[Initial Setup for creating a basic React App: Part 2](https://medium.com/@bhavyagupta1203/initial-setup-for-creating-a-basic-react-app-94818922108a)

[Posting Form data from ReactJS to MySQL database via Spring Boot Application: Part 3](https://medium.com/@bhavyagupta1203/posting-form-data-from-reactjs-to-mysql-database-via-spring-boot-application-ea0c947c4b82)

Answer (score 0):

In a typical/modern web application, you have well defined roles/purposes for each part of the system. From your question, it appears that you intend for the roles to be interchanged and that might the source of your troubles here.

Let;s look closely at your set-up:

- **Client-side/Front-end (JavaScript/React)**
  This is simply an enabler for a user to interact with your actual application.
   In your set-up, this should render the form and capture registration data.
- **Server-side/Back-end (Java/SpringBoot)**
  This is your application layer where most processing happens (business logic).
  In your set-up, this is where your MVC happens. And essentially, after any required validation, this layer then communicates with the Database.
- **Database-layer (SQL or NoSQL)**
  This is the layer that you utilize to store and persist data within your app.
   In your set-up, you are using MySQL to handle your data.

Already your backend is already exposing `endpoints` which you are consuming at the front-end via `axios`. Therefore the direct answer to your question lies in getting `SpringBoot` to work with your `MySQL` in order to persist your data.

Here is an [official tutorial on how to access data with MySQL](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) from the spring team.

Comment: Thank u for your answer :), but I am not able to understand how to connect my application to MySQL. Can u provide some links or any sort of code  related to how can I connect with MySQL

Comment: I have added the link within the answer, that should be of help.