# How do i pass data from one component to another in realtime?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to pass data that I pull from a SQLDatabase into another component that would display it. I'm not sure how to do it exactly...

**In my App.js**

This calls CustomList

```
import CustomList from './components/FlatList';
export default function App() {
  return(
    <CustomList />
  );
};
```

which

**In my CustomList**

```
import Data from './Data';
...
export default function CustomList() {
    //Sets up Getter , Setter , Initial Data
    const [data, setData] = useState(Data);
    ...

    return (
       <FlatList 
            ListHeaderComponent = {header}
            data = {data}
            keyExtractor = { (item) => (item.id).toString()}
            ItemSeparatorComponent = { () => <View style={styles.itemSeparator}></View>}
            contentContainerStyle={ {borderBottomColor:'grey', borderBottomWidth: 1} }
            renderItem = { ({item, index}) => <ListItem item={item} index={index}/>}
       />
...
```

The CustomList above works if I import hard-coded data below

**In my Data.js**

```
const Data = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Boadb'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Joe'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Jane'},
    {id: 4, text: 'John'},
    {id: 5, text: 'Janet'},
    {id: 6, text: 'Janet'},
    {id: 7, text: 'Janet'},
    {id: 8, text: 'Janet'},
];

export default Data;
```

However, I want a real-time syncing database that will update the CustomList whenever changes are made.

**In my SQLData.js**

```
let helperArray;
...
export default function SQLData() {
     ...
     function querySuccess(tx, results) {
         ...
         helperArray = [];
         //Go through each item in dataset
         for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         let row = results.rows.item(i);
         helperArray.push(row);
      }
    ...
    return ();
  };
```

As you can see from the code above, I have put the data pulled from the SQLDatabase into a variable helperArray. I was wondering how do I import it similarly like 'Data.js' and have it output the same way! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### How do I pass data from one component to another in realtime?

There are several ways of doing this, one of which is through props. It technically is not real time, but it is close and probably fast enough for your use case. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html 
Good news! You are already doing this here:

```
<FlatList 
  ListHeaderComponent = {header}
  data = {data}
  keyExtractor = { (item) => (item.id).toString()}
  ItemSeparatorComponent = { () => <View style={styles.itemSeparator}></View>}
  contentContainerStyle={ {borderBottomColor:'grey', borderBottomWidth: 1} }
  renderItem = { ({item, index}) => <ListItem item={item} index={index}/>}
/>
```

Where you are passing data as a prop to FlatList referencing CustomList's data variable.

```
      data = {data}
```

So you want helperArray's information in the CustomList component. You could utilize React's [Lifecycle](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) to fetch the information once in your App Component's (or CustomList's) [mounting phase](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting). The mounting phase is when an instance of a component is being created and inserted into the DOM:

If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, [componentDidMount is a good place to instantiate the network request](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).
Once you received the data from the DB, set it to your Component's state. Then if you are loading it in the App Component change your return statement to be:

```
return(
  <CustomList data = {helperArray(the reference to the state )}/>
);
```

### Another question is

> However, I want a real-time syncing database that will update the CustomList whenever changes are made.

So the answer to this is very tricky and will depend on your tech stack. You could host a back-end application that acts as a REST controller for your front end.
If you are not familiar it would look like this 
Front End (React WebApp) makes changes to data and clicks submit (or any other event) -> 
Front End will use a library(Axios.js is very popular with React) to make a HTTP request to the backend -> 
BackEnd (Spring server / Node.js server, etc.) receives that HTTP request processes it, then creates a connection with a DB (SQL, Mongo, etc.)-> 
Back End will then use that connection to write to the database (if using Spring JPA, is using Node.js mssql) -> 
Now with your updated data in your DB, the next time someone visits your front end application it will make a request to get the data from your back end then populate the page with that data. 
[Here is another great answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332643/sending-data-to-database-in-react-js-web-application)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. What I am planning on making is something with also syncs with a local database in case of having no internet, the data will sync once connected to the internet. I'm still confused on how exactly to get the variable "helperArray" from SQLData.js into CustomList.js

Comment: I see! So what I'm essentially doing is importing SQLData.js into the App.js during mounting phase by calling the component SQLData.js in App.js and setting the resulting data as a prop for CustomList. I'm still a little bit confused on how exactly to call and return the data from SQLData.js. I've changed helperArray into " const [helperArray, setArray] = useState([]); and pushing data into that.

Comment: Move the code from: export default function SQLData() into the componentDidMount life-cycle hook of one of your components. Your component should have a state, once your helperArray is populated setState(helperArray) to make that component's state the value of helperArray. If you did the data collection in the App component, pass your state to your CustomList Component as a prop, if you did the data collection in the CustomList Component you have the data in your state.

Comment: Is there anyway to separate it into a separate file? I'm trying to make my code as clean as possible where I don't have to clutter too many functions into one file!

Comment: Generally you should make REST calls with a service, services in react are a bit tricky but if you are up for a challenge read [this](https://the-guild.dev/blog/injectable-services-in-react). This uses the [Context/Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that comes with React. If that is too complicated, you can also keep the function in another file just be sure to export the function from that file, import that function in the file you want to use, and return the correct values inside the exported function(currently it looks like you return() (nothing) instead of return helperArray.

Comment: Ah! So what I need to do is "import { SQLData } from SQLData.js" in either my Apps.js or CustomList.js which will import all the functions and then I can call my query function. i.e. SQLData.querySuccess(); which should return my list of data in either Apps.js or CustomList.js.  And in my SQLData.js file, it should be r"eturn ( {helperArray} );"

Comment: Export default in JavaScript will make that the default export(obvious I know) so you could do import anyReferenceName from “SQLData.js”;. Where anyReferenceName can be any name you want, it does not need to be the function name. Regular exports (not default) need to be referenced by name like import {getData} from “SQLData.js”;. I would recommend importing it in your App component as if you make another Component as a child to App (like your CustomList) it is easy to pass down through props. If you import your data into CustomList you might encounter a problem.